# How to normalize mutual information between to real-valued random variables?

Tags: machine-learning, random-variable, scikit-learn, mutual-information

How can I normalize mutual information between to real-valued random variables using `Python` or `R`? `sklearn.metrics.normalized_mutual_info_score` seems to work for only nominal data. Or how to interpret the unnormalized scores?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you cannot just do that as-is.

Mutual information requires knowledge of your data generating probability density function. Nominal data naturally defines such pdf with counts. Continuous data doesn't.

There are two ways to handle that: either assume some pdf, like something parametric (or obtained with kernel smoothing), or convert your data to nominal data (this can be done for example using bucketing).